# Can I start a range with a column header word?

Tags: excel, vba

I have several tables which are basically stacked on each other that have step columns all in column A.  So first table starts Steps (column header) then goes 1 - n (whatever)   below it and I have a button next to it that adds rows right below that table.  Then A few rows are skipped and I have another similar table below that has column header STEPS1 and lists the step number below that with another button to add rows.  I have code that will color certain cells in the table based on which step # the row is although when I add a bunch of rows my defined range for coloring cells expends and starts to color cells that I dont want colored.  So, can I define a range that starts with a column header instead of lets say `For all c in Range("A23:A32")`

Here is some code:

```
Dim C As Range
For Each C In Range("A22:A38")
            If C = 1 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B12").Interior.Color 'whatever colour you need
            ElseIf C = 2 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B13").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 3 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B14").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 4 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B15").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 5 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B16").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 6 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B17").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 7 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B18").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 8 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B19").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 9 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B20").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 10 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B21").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 11 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B22").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 12 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B23").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 13 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B24").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 14 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B25").Interior.Color
            ElseIf C = 15 Then
                Union(Cells(C.row, 2), Cells(C.row, 5), Cells(C.row, 8), Cells(C.row, 11), Cells(C.row, 14)).Interior.Color = Range("B26").Interior.Color
            End If
        Next C
        Loop
```

My problem is that if I add a bunch of rows to each table, the range that I set is now doesnt cover the whole table per say.  I want a range that can find the column header like STEP1 or STEP2 and go until there is a blank row

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting here?

Comment: I wasnt really sure how and not quite sure conditional formatting would accomplish what I need since the tables are very dynamic

Comment: As a side note, you can do that whole string of ifs with a single statement.  The whole repeated bit = Range("B" & C+11).Interior.Color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a read and see if it's useful.  You'd call this Subroutine with the name of your header in column A.

```
Sub ScanAndColor(tblName As String)

    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1

    'scan down until you find tblName, this is like "STEPS" or "STEPS1" or whatever
    Do While Cells(row, 1).Text <> tblName

        'just read the next row
        row = row + 1

        'since we're letting someone else tell us what value to stop at, maybe we should add some infinite loop protection
        If row = 1000 Then GoTo EscapeHatch
    Loop

    'push down one column to start reading just under the headers
    row = row + 1

    'scan down through the table until we hit some whitespace
    Do While Cells(row, 1).Text <> ""

        'in each iteration, grab every 3rd column from col 2 and assign it a color
        '  according to the code in the first cell.
        For col = 2 To 14 Step 3
            Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = Cells(Cells(row, 1) + 15, 2).Interior.Color

        Next col

        'increment the row
        row = row + 1
    Loop

EscapeHatch:
End Sub
```